# A bunch of synonym requests and a couple of burninates

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request, clean-up, burninate-request

I was bored and spent couple of hours browsing the tags on SO. I found some tags that look like they need some help, most of them are synonym requests, but there are also some burninate requests or tag-wiki changes.

However, I am human and I bet some of these will be wrong, so each case should be properly analyzed.

**Note:** for the synonym-requests, the order of items in doesn't mean anything special (so each case must be reviewed to find a proper master tag).

(For easier navigation, I made this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cV3zq/6/embedded/result/) that displays a table with links and comments)

`//` means I opened a note
`?` means I have doubts
`=` means to synonymize (order NOT important)

- [auto-indent](/questions/tagged/auto-indent) = [auto-indentation](/questions/tagged/auto-indentation)
- [auto-update](/questions/tagged/auto-update) = [autoupdate](/questions/tagged/autoupdate) = [automatic-updates](/questions/tagged/automatic-updates)
- [admin](/questions/tagged/admin) = [administrator](/questions/tagged/administrator) //?
- [alt](/questions/tagged/alt) = [alt-attribute](/questions/tagged/alt-attribute)
- [arguments](/questions/tagged/arguments) = [args](/questions/tagged/args) //?
- [ajax-request](/questions/tagged/ajax-request) = [ajax.request](/questions/tagged/ajax.request)
- [bold](/questions/tagged/bold) //the tag-wiki never suggests "bold" as boldder text
- [brain](/questions/tagged/brain) //only one Q seems to not talk about our brains
- [builtin](/questions/tagged/builtin) //some Qs are meant to be "built-in"
- [character](/questions/tagged/character) = [chars](/questions/tagged/chars) //?
- [code-efficiency](/questions/tagged/code-efficiency) = [coding-efficiency](/questions/tagged/coding-efficiency) = [performance](/questions/tagged/performance)
- [code-readability](/questions/tagged/code-readability) = [readability](/questions/tagged/readability) //?
- [coding-horrors](/questions/tagged/coding-horrors) = [anti-patterns](/questions/tagged/anti-patterns) //the tag "codinghorror" is NOT related
- [col](/questions/tagged/col) //cleanup for the ones that used it as "column" without any valid reason?, or turn them to "column"?
- [colspan](/questions/tagged/colspan) = [columnspan](/questions/tagged/columnspan)
- [combine](/questions/tagged/combine) = [merge](/questions/tagged/merge)
- [copy-paste](/questions/tagged/copy-paste) = [copy-and-paste](/questions/tagged/copy-and-paste)
- [days](/questions/tagged/days) //burninate
- [developer-tools](/questions/tagged/developer-tools) = [devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools)
- [die](/questions/tagged/die) //ambiguity with the tag "dice"
- [divide-by-zero](/questions/tagged/divide-by-zero) = [division-by-zero](/questions/tagged/division-by-zero)
- [do-it-yourself](/questions/tagged/do-it-yourself) //burninate
- [evil](/questions/tagged/evil) //burninate (or merge with "anti-paterns")
- [exe](/questions/tagged/exe) = [.exe](/questions/tagged/.exe) //maybe "executable" too?
- [exporting](/questions/tagged/exporting) = [export](/questions/tagged/export)

See also [list of tags that differ only by pluralization and hyphenation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags) (I have removed all my requests about those, and merged the missing ones to his list).

Comment: You missed f thru z.  Did you run afoul of the 30,000 character limit?  Are there additional follow-up meta posts in our future?

Comment: I am planning to do more in the next days, I stopped at _F_ for today

Comment: Which side is your proposed master tag, the left side or the right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey sadly, none (edit: I mean, one of them but don't know which). I would go very slow if I had to judge that (and I would probably get it wrong anyway). Sorry for that

Comment: I've killed off [tag:card-game], [tag:card-games], [tag:board-game], and [tag:board-games], as well as [tag:non-profit] which I happened to run across doing those.

Comment: [cheat-sheet] looks pretty meta also.

Comment: There is already a post with another comprehensive list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags

Comment: Please don't propose too many unrelated tag synonyms and burninations in the same post, as they're difficult to review. I've already posted an [automatically generated list of hyphentation/pluralization tag pairs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135985) (these have a high probability of being synonyms, but still need manual review, and feel free to open separate questions if there's a doubt). Could you remove these so that we can see the new candidates, like [tag:copy-paste]/[tag:copy-and-paste]?

Comment: @Gilles done, I compared the two lists, around 40 of mine were duplicates and found like 4 that weren't in your list (and included them). Hope this question is not a dup anymore

Comment: Shouldn't we merge [tag:die] with [tag:kill]?

Comment: I don't know about [columnspan], but `colspan` is the name of a HTML attribute, not just an abbreviation of the former

Comment: @Rosinante I don't like the idea, some languages use exactly those words for specific functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Burninated:**

<s>[board-game](/questions/tagged/board-game)</s> <s>[board-games](/questions/tagged/board-games)</s> <s>[card-game](/questions/tagged/card-game)</s> <s>[card-games](/questions/tagged/card-games)</s> <s>[non-profit](/questions/tagged/non-profit)</s> <s>[do-it-yourself](/questions/tagged/do-it-yourself)</s> <s>[evil](/questions/tagged/evil)</s>

**Synonymized:**

-

**Other (e.g cleanups, tag-wiki changes):**

[die](/questions/tagged/die)

---

**To be kept as is:**

[days](/questions/tagged/days)

[combine](/questions/tagged/combine) [merge](/questions/tagged/merge)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my opinion on some of them. This really should be separate posts, because there are many unrelated tags. Please do not take drastic action without taking the opinion of people who are familiar with each tag.

#### These look like exact synonyms

- [admin](/questions/tagged/admin) = [administrator](/questions/tagged/administrator), also [administration](/questions/tagged/administration) and [sysadmin](/questions/tagged/sysadmin) (there may be questions where [administration](/questions/tagged/administration) isn't about system administration, I haven't dug into that)
- [alt](/questions/tagged/alt) ← [alt-attribute](/questions/tagged/alt-attribute)
- [auto-indent](/questions/tagged/auto-indent) = [auto-indentation](/questions/tagged/auto-indentation)
- [auto-update](/questions/tagged/auto-update) = [autoupdate](/questions/tagged/autoupdate) = [automatic-updates](/questions/tagged/automatic-updates)
- [built-in](/questions/tagged/built-in) ← [builtin](/questions/tagged/builtin) = [builtins](/questions/tagged/builtins): while [builtin](/questions/tagged/builtin) serves to indicate the `builtin` builtin in [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) and `__builtin__` in [python](/questions/tagged/python), the meaning is sufficiently transparent that [built-in](/questions/tagged/built-in) can capture them all.
- [chars](/questions/tagged/chars): I think this tag should be merged into [character](/questions/tagged/character) (which already has [characters](/questions/tagged/characters) as a synonym), then deleted. [char](/questions/tagged/char), which is a keyword in some languages including [c](/questions/tagged/c) and does not denote a character, must remain a separate tag. After [chars](/questions/tagged/chars) disappears, due to the existence of [char](/questions/tagged/char), it will not be re-created.
- [code-efficiency](/questions/tagged/code-efficiency) = [coding-efficiency](/questions/tagged/coding-efficiency) → [performance](/questions/tagged/performance)
- [copy-paste](/questions/tagged/copy-paste) = [copy-and-paste](/questions/tagged/copy-and-paste)
- [divide-by-zero](/questions/tagged/divide-by-zero) = [division-by-zero](/questions/tagged/division-by-zero)
- [exporting](/questions/tagged/exporting) → [export](/questions/tagged/export)
   * [exe](/questions/tagged/exe) → [.exe](/questions/tagged/.exe) (but not [executable](/questions/tagged/executable), which is a lot broader; [exe](/questions/tagged/exe)/[.exe](/questions/tagged/.exe) is only about DOS/Windows programs)

#### These should stay

- [combine](/questions/tagged/combine) = [merge](/questions/tagged/merge): I disagree, “merging” is different from “combining” in too many contexts.
- [days](/questions/tagged/days): nothing wrong with that tag
- [die](/questions/tagged/die): needs to stay as the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and [php](/questions/tagged/php) function. I've retagged the others.

#### These need manual cleanup

- [ajax.request](/questions/tagged/ajax.request) looks like a specific library function. I don't know the subject, I can't tell if it needs its own tag.
- [args](/questions/tagged/args) has some uses where it means [arguments](/questions/tagged/arguments) and some where it means something else, such as the arguments to the main program in some languages (→ [command-line-arguments](/questions/tagged/command-line-arguments)), or `VA_ARGS` in [c](/questions/tagged/c).
- [brain](/questions/tagged/brain) (mixture of “brain teaser”, [artificial-intelligence](/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) and some technical meanings)
- [bold](/questions/tagged/bold) Given the relative obscurity of the Delphi framework compared to bold text, I think the Delphi uses should be manually renamed to [bold-for-delphi](/questions/tagged/bold-for-delphi).

#### Food for Trogdor

- [coding-horrors](/questions/tagged/coding-horrors)
- [developer-tools](/questions/tagged/developer-tools), [devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools)? (I'm not sure about these, there may be domains where these are technical terms)
- [do-it-yourself](/questions/tagged/do-it-yourself), [evil](/questions/tagged/evil) (removed from non-closed questions)

Comment: I pretty much agree with everything, just one note _"die: needs to stay..."_ I didn't suggest the opposite, I just pointed out the ambiguity with 'dice'