# Why is there an [implementation] tag, and why does it have 134 instances?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I would write an extended rationale for why [implementation](/questions/tagged/implementation) and everywhere it is used is ridiculous, if I did not think it was already self-evident.

Can it be speedy-delete-blacklisted, or does anyone have a *"no, that's a useful tag"* argument?

Comment: There are times when "implementation" *could* be a legitimate descriptive tag. But it would only be in combination with some standard (XML-implementation, OpenGL-implemenentation, as opposed to questions about XML/OpenGL as specifications). Of course, since questions about some XML implementation have nothing to do with questions about an OpenGL implementation, it still wouldn't work. I don't think full-on burnination is necessary, but it does need to be deconstructed.

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess to me the value of a tag has a lot to do with if it enables some kind of discovery.  Some disagree with [why I like playing-cards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149700/), but I like it because if someone asks a question about solitaire and drawing cards in Java then you get a taxonomy that opens up related issues.  A query on `[playing-cards] [java]` might get you somewhere.  My critique of [tag:implementation] is just not being able to paint a scenario in my mind where it does any good...

Comment: Every one of these I've looked at could benefit from editing off that tag, and most should be closed.

Comment: Apparently it's not self-evident to 134 people, so please write up your extended rationale, to be included in the `[implementation]` tag wiki.  ;)